# Comparing different totals between 2 tables and putting that into its own column

Tags: sql, sql-server

The current results i have are this

```
| MonthYear | Table1 Amount | Table2 Amount |
|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|    Jun-17 |           100 |           125 |
|    Sep-17 |            50 |            50 |
```

I am comparing the totals from the two tables on a monthly basis. When the total is different between the 2 tables i want to add the difference to another column

```
| MonthYear | Table1 Amount | Table2 Amount | Unknown |
|-----------|---------------|---------------|---------|
|    Jun-17 |           100 |           125 |      25 |
|    Sep-17 |            50 |            50 |       0 |
```

Which i have achieved but how do i add the case statement as a row instead or a column e.g output like this

```
| MonthYear | Table1 Amount | Table2 Amount |
|-----------|---------------|---------------|
|    Jun-17 |           100 |           125 | 
|    Sep-17 |            50 |            50 | 
|   Unknown |               |            25 |
```

Can this be done? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8843b/1

Comment: You can use `UNION`, also can we see your query & sample data ?

Comment: @Susang i need to compare results between the two tables so i think a join is more useful - go onto my sql fiddle its all on there

Comment: If you have another row of difference value then where do you wish to display ? in the another row at the last ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROLLUP`?

```
SELECT  
  t2.MonthYear,  
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(t2.MonthYear) = 0
       THEN sum(t1.Amount)
  END                                     AS [Table1 Amount] ,
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(t2.MonthYear) = 0
       THEN sum(t2.Amount)
       ELSE SUM(t2.amount) - SUM(t1.amount) 
  END                                     AS [Table2 Amount]   
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN
Table2 T2
ON T1.Code1 = T2.Code1
AND T1.InvoiceNumber = T2.InvoiceNumber
GROUP BY T2.MonthYear WITH ROLLUP
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8843b/4

But putting the value under the table2 amount seems, ummm, a mis-representation?